# How to using Jquery for add / delete buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

i want to ask something how to add button for adding a new row in table using `Jquery` and if added a new row, in first row changed to delete button. and user can delete each per rows.

I want to make a report in which there is a daily report.

what I want to make is that the daily report has an add and delete button. which later will be saved as a report into PDF format using DomPDF.

```html
<div class="card-body">
    <div class="table-responsive">
    @csrf
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive" id="tb">
        <thead class="thead-dark ">
            <tr>
                <th class="align-middle text-center" style="width:23%">Date</th>
                <th class="align-middle text-center" style="width:10%">Start</th>
                <th class="align-middle text-center" style="width:10%">Finish</th>
                <th class="align-middle text-center" style="width:20%">Title</th>
                <th class="align-middle text-center" style="width:32%">Description</th>
                <th class="align-middle text-center" style="width:5%">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="align-middle text-center" ><input type="text" name="tb_tanggal" id="tb_tanggal" class="form-control input-lg datepicker" placeholder="25 Januari 2021"></td>
                <td class="align-middle text-center" ><input type="text" name="tb_mulai" id="tb_mulai" class="form-control input-lg timepicker" placeholder="08:00" ></td>
                <td class="align-middle text-center" ><input type="text" name="tb_selesai" id="tb_selesai" class="form-control input-lg timepicker" placeholder="17:00"></td>
                <td class="align-middle" ><input type="text" name="tb_judul" id="tb_judul" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Judul Laporan"></td>
                <td class="align-middle" ><textarea type="text" name="tb_desc" id="tb_desc" class="form-control" rows="3"  style="resize: none;"></textarea></td>
                <td class="align-middle text-center" ><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger cyan btn-block"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-window-minimize"></i></a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="align-middle text-center" ><input type="text" name="tb_tanggal" id="tb_tanggal" class="form-control input-lg datepicker" placeholder="25 Januari 2021"></td>
                <td class="align-middle text-center" ><input type="text" name="tb_mulai" id="tb_mulai" class="form-control input-lg timepicker" placeholder="08:00" ></td>
                <td class="align-middle text-center" ><input type="text" name="tb_selesai" id="tb_selesai" class="form-control input-lg timepicker" placeholder="17:00"></td>
                <td class="align-middle" ><input type="text" name="tb_judul" id="tb_judul" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Judul Laporan"></td>
                <td class="align-middle" ><textarea type="text" name="tb_desc" id="tb_desc" class="form-control" rows="3"  style="resize: none;"></textarea></td>
                <td class="align-middle text-center" ><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger cyan btn-block"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-window-minimize"></i></a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="align-middle text-center" ><input type="text" name="tb_tanggal" id="tb_tanggal" class="form-control input-lg datepicker" placeholder="25 Januari 2021"></td>
                <td class="align-middle text-center" ><input type="text" name="tb_mulai" id="tb_mulai" class="form-control input-lg timepicker" placeholder="08:00" ></td>
                <td class="align-middle text-center" ><input type="text" name="tb_selesai" id="tb_selesai" class="form-control input-lg timepicker" placeholder="17:00"></td>
                <td class="align-middle" ><input type="text" name="tb_judul" id="tb_judul" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Judul Laporan"></td>
                <td class="align-middle" ><textarea type="text" name="tb_desc" id="tb_desc" class="form-control" rows="3"  style="resize: none;"></textarea>{{ old('') }}</td>
                <td class="align-middle text-center" ><a href="#" class="btn btn-success cyan btn-block"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-plus"></i></a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

table form:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add a common class 'delete-row-btn' to all delete buttons

```
// Delete row on delete button click
    $(document).on('click', '.delete-row-btn', function (e) {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove()
    });
```

also add a common class 'add-row-btn' to all plus buttons

```
// add new row on plus button click and change this button to delete button
$(document).on('click', '.add-row-btn', function (e) {
    // add new row
    $('#tb').append('<tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>');

    //change this plus btn to delete button
    $(this).closest('td').html('<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger cyan btn-block delete-row-btn"><i class="zmdi zmdi-window-minimize"></i></a>')
});
```

Html content of the row need to be entered inside the "append" function

Comment: still can't add / delete using button. here's the code https://pastebin.com/AbEsT9bP

Comment: please tell me if any console errors are shown

Comment: there's no error. but when i click it, can't do action anything (add/ remove). neither using anchor tag or button tag.

Comment: or maybe i got mistake on the loop https://prnt.sc/zl0btt. im just click once, and then it show 16 datas.


I want to make a report in which there is a daily report.

what I want to make is that the daily report has an add and delete button. which later will be saved as a report into PDF format using DomPDF.